# How do I change the style of just a part of the tagline?

Tags: css, description

I'd like my tagline to have specific styling - but not all of the tagline, but just some words should be bold/italised/different color. How do I wrap `<span>` around specific tagline words? Can it even be done?

I know how to change the style of tagline in general (targeting `.masthead-content p`), but this affects the whole tagline. I need to target specific part of it.
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick search online for html in your tagline came to this site: https://www.kirstencassidy.com/allow-html-code-in-wordpress-tagline/

It seems like it is your answer.

It explains that you would update your theme file to use the echo html_entity_decode function:

```
<h2 class="tagline"><?php echo html_entity_decode(get_bloginfo('description'));?></h2>
```

Then, you can just use html in your admin > settings page like so:

```
This is <span class="some-class">my tagline</span>
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I did google, but must have been using the wrong terms.

Comment: No worries @Newbie - I'm new to this site as a contributor, but if this is the answer, please mark it as such (if you haven't already)